# Regular expression replace in notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to do a regex find and replace:

every

```
"<xsl:if test="any/text()"
```

has to be replaced by

```
"<xsl:if test="normalize-space(any/text())"
```

I have tried Find:

```
<xsl:if test="(.*)/text()
```

replace by

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(\1/text())
```

but it doesn't work..

so every if statement where /text() is present, replace it by normalize-space(../text())

thx

Answer (score 6):

`()` are special chars in regexes. You need to escape them to be able to match them. Like this:

```
<xsl:if test="(.*)/text\(\)
```